# Operate over list of pure functions

Tags: map, operators, pure-function

I have list of pure functions (All functions are `InterpolatingFunction`) *i.e*

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, ...}
```

and I would like to end up with

```
{ (a[#]/b[#])&, (c[#]/d[#])&,(e[#]/f[#])&,...}
```

the closest I have got is to do

```
(Divide @@ Through[#[x]]) & /@ {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
```

> ```
> {a[x]/b[x], c[x]/d[x], e[x]/f[x]}
> ```

but these are not pure functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This perhaps:

```
Function[{a, b}, a[#]/b[#] &] @@@ {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
(* Out: {a[#1]/b[#1] &, c[#1]/d[#1] &, e[#1]/f[#1] &} *)
```

Mr.Wizard's way of writing it (see comment) looks like this in the frontend:

[image: frontend]

Comment: Can also be written: `({x, y} \[Function] x[#]/y[#] &) @@@ {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I hadn't seen `\[Function]` before! I added an image to the answer so everyone can see how it looks there.

Answer (score 7):

You can almost always turn to replacement patterns when you need to transform expressions:

```
Cases[
  {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}},
  {x_, y_} :> (x[#]/y[#] &)
]
```

> ```
> {a[#1]/b[#1] &, c[#1]/d[#1] &, e[#1]/f[#1] &}
> ```

`Cases` defaults to *levelspec* `{1}` so this is safer than using `/.`.

Answer (score 4):

Also:

```
With[{a = #1, b = #2}, a[#]/b[#] &] & @@@ {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}
```

or

```
x[#]/y[#] & /. {x -> #1, y -> #2} & @@@ {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}

(* {a[#1]/b[#1] &, c[#1]/d[#1] &, e[#1]/f[#1] &} *)
```