# Using Through with SlotSequence

Tags: evaluation, pure-function

I have an expression consisting of a few pure functions added together like so:

```
f+g+h
```

I want to add the bodies of these functions together and make that a pure function. Usually I would do this by finding the maximum number of arguments (`maxArgs`) required to fill the functions `f`, `g` and `h`, and then create my added function like so:

```
newFunc = Evaluate[Through[(f+g+h)@@Slot/@Range@maxArgs]] &;
```

The `Evaluate` here is important for a couple of reasons impertinent to this question. Just know that it is **necessary to evaluate the function body**.

The problem with this method is that in general, I won't always know what `maxArgs` will be. Technically, I could find this value by using [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56672/14593), but I'm worried about the performance and robustness of this method.

I thought that I might circumvent the need to specify a number of slots by doing this:

```
newFunc = Evaluate[Through[(f+g+h)[##]]]&
```

But *Mathematica*'s output at this point throws an error, saying that the slots of the functions *f*, *g* and *h* cannot be filled from `##`. I understand that this is because `##` appears as just one symbol to *Mathematica*.

So how might I evaluate `Through` without specifying the number of slots I will need?

**Example:**

Given:

```
f = #&;
g = Function[{a,b,c}, a^3 - b];
h = - #1^2 + #2 &;
```

My desired output is produced by:

```
myFunc = Evaluate[Through[(f+g+h)[#1,#2,#3]]&;
```

The important bit here is the `Evaluate`. I want to evaluate the function body completely before creating the function. The problem with the code above is that I had to explicitly enter the maximum number of slots required by the pure functions. In this case, three slots were required. In general, I may be using functions that take 3 arguments, or 5, or 72, etc.

In my notebook, I will not know ahead of time how many slots will be used by these functions.

Comment: Suppose that when you use expr, that f expects 3 arguments, g expects 2 and h expects 5, how would you plan to invoke expr?

Comment: @JohnMcGee - I would expect `expr` to end up with five slots. `f` would take its fill from the first 3, g from the first 2, and h from all of them. In other words, I would want the equivalent of `expr = Through[(f+g+h)[#1,#2,#3,#4,#5]]`.

Comment: Related: [(28056)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28056/121), [(28064)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28064/121),
[(48786)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48786/121), [(56665)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56665/121),
[(63747)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63747/121),
[(87464)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/87464/121)

Comment: You have now introduced `Derivative` in your examples.  Is this the only other expression that yo wish to treat like a function or are you going to add another one as soon as answers are updated to handle `Derivative`?  Also `# & + Derivative[1]` and `Derivative[1] + # &` are surely different as the first one is `(# &) + Derivative[1]` whereas the second is `(Derivative[1] + #) &`.  I think your question is not well specified at present as it is not clear what extent of heads you expect to be handled.  I am going to put this on hold until you can provide an *exhaustive* specification.

Comment: `Through[(Derivative[1] + (# &))[#1]]`... think about it...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I've tried to condense and focus the question, please let me know if there's more I can do.

Comment: @Myridium I apologize if I appear uncooperative but that is not my intent.  However there is no *universal and robust* way to determine the number of arguments of a function (referencing [(7040)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7040/121) and [(56665)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56665/121)).  One then wonders what compromise you would find acceptable?  Your current example uses `ArcTan`, a function that has both one and two parameter forms.  You *must* explain how such problems are to be handled if this question is to be answerable.  (continued)

Comment: @Myridium Also, functions can have different evaluation rules for symbolic or numeric arguments.  Therefore the class of functions that you wish to operate upon needs to be *clearly specified* rather than assumed and changing with each update.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah, thank you, you have brought to my attention some technical ambiguities that I didn't realize were there! I can see some of the issues now, and in this light I will narrow the scope of my question to only pure functions.

Comment: Is my answer in its current form a solution in that case or are there other issues?  If there are please make them apparent.  I look forward to your (final?) update. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your question and comments again, and assuming that none of your pure functions contain SlotSequence, I think maybe this will work for you:

```
combine[expr_] := Max[
   Cases[expr, Slot[n_] :> n, {-2}],
   Cases[expr, Verbatim[Function][x_List, __] :> Length@Unevaluated@x, {1}]
 ] // Function @@ {Through[expr @@ Array[Slot, #]]} &
```

Test:

```
f = # &;
g = Function[{a}, a^2];
h = (-2 #1 + #3) &;

combine[f + g + h]
```

> ```
> -#1 + #1^2 + #3 &
> ```

And now also:

```
f = Function[{a}, a];
g = Function[{a}, a^2];
h = Function[{a, b, c}, (-2 a + c)];

combine[f + g + h]
```

> ```
> -#1 + #1^2 + #3 &
> ```

Of course as rasher/ciao points out this doesn't work with e.g. `combine[f+g+h+f+g+h]` but that is because `f + f` evaluates to `2 f` and `Through` only works on the level one head.  If something besides `Through` behavior is desired that will need to be specified.

Comment: Try `combine[f+g+h+f+g+h]`...

Comment: @ciao - Indeed, this doesn't work in general. I don't understand the usage of the `levelspec` parameter in `Cases` here. `combine` fails to produce the desired output for `combine[Derivative[1] + #&]` although swapping those arguments works...

Comment: I'm not even sure I understand what OP is after :=}

Comment: Upon investigation, I can see that this will only work for functions written as expressions involving slots. So this suffers the same issue as belisarius and user8074's answers.

Comment: @ciao But that is not a problem with my code, it is simply the behavior of `Through` as the OP requested.

Comment: @Myridium re: "only work for functions written as expressions involving slots" sorry, you're right, I forgot to count named arguments.  However even correcting that I have no idea what `combine[Derivative[1] + #&]` is supposed to produce.

Comment: It should produce the same thing as `combine[#& + Derivative[1]]` produces. Namely: `(#1 + Derivative[1][#1]) &`

Comment: @ciao - I've updated my question; hopefully it better articulates what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to this question to help us both (mostly me) understand what exactly I was looking for. This solution meets my needs, cheers.

Comment: @Myridium You are welcome.  Thank you for having a good attitude about the temporary "on hold" status, and thanks also for the Accept.

Answer (score 2):

Is this near to what you are looking for?

```
    ClearAll[f, g, h]

    f1[s__] := Total@Take[{s}, 3];

    f2[s__] := Times @@ Take[{s}, 2];

    f3[s__] := {s}[[1]] {s}[[3]] - {s}[[2]] {s}[[4]];

    expr = Through[(f + g + h)[##]] &

    w = expr /. {f -> f1, g -> f2, h -> f3};

    w[5, 6, 7, 8]


(* 35 *)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid not; you've appended `&` to the end of `In[108]` and this delays evaluation of `Through` until `w` is supplied with arguments. I want `expr` to evaluate as an expression involving `Slot`s.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do it with `Through[ ]`. The following works:

```
f = {#1, #2} &;
g = Sin[{#1, #2}/#3] &;
h = Cos[{#1 + #2, #3 + #4 + #5}] &;
expr = Evaluate[(Plus @@ (First /@ {f, g, h}))] &

(* {Cos[#1 + #2] + Sin[#1/#3] + #1, Cos[#3 + #4 + #5] + Sin[#2/#3] + #2}  & *)

expr[a, b, c, d, e]
(* {a + Cos[a + b] + Sin[a/c], b + Cos[c + d + e] + Sin[b/c]} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work for functions written with `Slots`, but not with another pure function such as: `Function[{a}, a^2]`

Comment: In reality, I am dealing with compositions of pure functions, and this approach of taking the `First` part doesn't work then.

Comment: @Myridium You may expect all kind of weird things on that setup `Function[{a}, {#1, a}] &`

Comment: Fair point, but for my purposes, I would like to evaluate the functions anyway with slots as their arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Could this work for you?

```
f = # &;
g = #^2 &;
h = (-2 #1 + #3) &;

totalfunc = (f + g + h) /.
   f_[fl__Function] :>
       Module[{arg = {fl} /. Function -> List, int},
           int = f @@ arg;
           Function @@ (Evaluate[int])
       ]

totalfunc[6, 3, 3] ==> 33
```

The replacement rule is rather general.

**EDIT**:

In the case you mention a slight modification is necessary:

```
f = #1 & ; 
g = #1^2 & ; 
h = #1^3 + #3^3 & ; 
k = Function[{a}, a^4]; 
j = Function[{a, b}, a^5 + b^5];


ClearAll[makevarlist];
makevarlist[f_Function] :=
  Module[{slots},
   If[Length[f] > 1,
    slots = Slot /@ Range[Length[First[f]]];
    {slots, Last[f] /. Thread[First[f] -> slots]}
    ,
    {{}, List @@ f}
   ]
  ];


totalfunc = (f + g + h + k + j) /.
  f_[fl__Function] :>
   Module[{arg, int, vars},
    arg = makevarlist /@ {fl};
    int = f @@ (Last /@ arg);
    Function @@ (Evaluate[int])
   ]
```

> totalfunc  =>  #1^5 + #1^4 + #1^3 + #1^2 + #1 + #2^5 + #3^3 &

Comment: This is essentially the same as @belisarius 's solution and suffers the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

My quick-n-dirty take on this:

```
mergef = Module[{ds = Symbol /@ ("s" <> ToString@# & /@ Range@100), fs = ##, rf},
    rf = Plus@Through[fs[Sequence @@ ds]];
    Function @@ {Take[ds, Max[Position[ds, #] & /@ 
                 Cases[rf, Alternatives @@ ds, Infinity]]], rf}] &;

(* do some stuff *)
f = # &;
g = Function[{a}, a^2];
h = (-2 #1 + #3) &;
k = #6*10 &;

resfn = mergef[f, g, h, f, g, h, k]
resfn[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

(*
Function[{s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6}, -2 s1 + 2 s1^2 + 2 s3 + 10 s6]
82
*)

mergef[resfn, resfn][2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

(* 164 *)

(* using *belisarius*' functions *)

mergef[f1, f2, f3][5, 6, 7, 8]

(* 35 *)
```

Comment: Am I mistaken, or does this work only up to 100 slots? If that is the case, then I may as well use `expr = Through[(f+g+h)@@Slot/@Range@100]`

Comment: @Myridium: yes, that's just a static choice I made - one would question the sanity of writing a function with that many arguments, but can be set to whatever... as far as your comment code, try that with e.g. the example I commented to Mr. W... in any case, as noted this was barfed out in a minute or two, to perhaps give some ideas, nothing more.